# Build abstract filter function filled from json array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I want to filter a List of processes based on a location which the user can apply within an `ActionSheet`.
The problem is that the criteria can vary once in a while and I don't want to deploy a new version because of it. So I decided to push the filters via a centralized JSON file. It is kind of hard to explain so I'll show you an example.

This is my example JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Location A",
        "filter": [
            {
                "crit1": [
                    "A",
                    "B"
                ], // this must be an AND operand because another crit follows
                "crit2": [
                    "1",
                    "2"
                ]
            }, // this must be an OR operand because another filter follows
            {
                "crit1": [
                    "R"
                ],
                "crit3": [
                    "11",
                    "22"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Location B",
        "filter": [
            {
                "crit1": [
                    "C",
                    "D",
                    "E"
                ],
                "crit2": [
                    "L7"
                ]
            },
            {
                "crit1": [
                    "R"
                ],
                "crit3": [
                    "600451"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "All Locations",
        "filter": [
            {
                "crit1": [],
                "crit2": [],
                "crit3": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I've got a `ProcessList` where every `Process` has each `crit` value to compare to.
The clue is that every `filter` object, if there is more than one, shall be combined with `or` operand.
But in the `filter` e.g. in `Location A` with `crit1` and `crit2` shall be and `and` operand if there is more than one...

Is this even possible?
The more I think about it and trying it my frustration increases.

Hope you can help me out!

EDIT:
Here's my approach:

```
void BuildLocationFilterFromJSON(Location location)
{
    List<Process> _tempProcessList = null;
    if (location.filter != null) // because i added a default local location for the first use which is null therefore
    {
        foreach (var filter in location.filter) // handling the first array
        {
            if (filter.crit1 != null) // could be non-existing
            {
                foreach (var value in filter.crit1)
                {
                    var _filteredProcessList = ProcessList.Where(x => x.crit1Value == value) as Process;
                    _tempProcessList.Add(_filteredProcessList);
                }
            }
            if (filter.crit2 != null) // could be non-existing
            {
                foreach (var value in filter.crit2)
                {
                    Console.Write(value);
                }
            }
            if (filter.crit3 != null) // could be non-existing
            {
                foreach (var value in filter.crit3)
                {
                    Console.Write(value);
                }
            }

            ProcessList = _tempProcessList; // Update the real ProcessList
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any C# code to show your attempts so far?

Comment: So far I deleted everything again.

Comment: What do you have till now? Where are you stuck? parsing the json? applying the filters to the list? something else?

Comment: I am tryining to work out something again and will add my code.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question, let me know once you update the code.

Comment: Updated it. But I am getting an Exception

Comment: Where do you get the exception?

Comment: Solved it. My `Where` function remains `null`, but I matched a value for testing so it shouldn't be null. Any idea? Another Linq method maybe? So far my ProcessList is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is at this line:

```
ProcessList.Where(x => x.crit1Value == value) as Process;
```

Your `Where` returns an `IEnumerable<Process>`, not a `Process`.

Therefore either use `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault`, or continue treat it as an `IEnumerable`. But surely it could never be casted to `Process`.

In you specific case, you add it to a list, so you can use `AddRange`

Comment: Sounds legit. I'll give it a shot on monday. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: Do you know which function I have to uses when I want to create a new list with the matches? Like `_filteredList = _tempList.Where(x => x.Crit1== Crit1);`?

Comment: Add `.ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

I would create classes representing your criteria (to be used when deserializing the Json) and use an approach like the following:

```
public class LocationSelector
{
    public class LocationFilter
    {
        public List<string> Criteria1 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Criteria2 { get; set; }
        public List<string> Criteria3 { get; set; }

        // We use this method to transfor a list of values
        //  (Criteria1) in a SINGLE predicate
        private Func<MyType, bool> Criteria1ToPredicate()
        {
            if (Criteria1 == null) return (obj) => true;

            // if Criteria1 is a simple list of strings,
            // you can use contains
            return (obj) => Criteria1.Contains(obj.Criteria1.Value);
        }

        private Func<MyType, bool> Criteria2ToPredicate()
        {
            if (Criteria2 == null) return (obj) => true;

            // if you cannot use contains, you can use Any
            return (obj) => Criteria2.Any(critVal => obj.Criteria2 == critVal);
        }

        private Func<MyType, bool> Criteria3ToPredicate()
        {
            if (Criteria3 == null) return (obj) => true;

            // a slightly different use case is using All to
            // to ensure that every value matches
            return (obj) => Criteria3.All(crit3 => obj.Criteria3.Value);
        }

        public Func<MyType, bool> ToPredicate()
        {
            // this is critical: the results of this three
            // methods are three invokable funcs
            var pred1 = Criteria1ToPredicate();
            var pred2 = Criteria2ToPredicate();
            var pred3 = Criteria3ToPredicate();

            // we return the ANDing of the three funcs
            return (obj) => pred1(obj) && pred2(obj) && pred3(obj);
        }
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<LocationFilter> Filter { get; set; }

    // This method puts the different filters in OR
    public Func<MyType, bool> ToPredicate()
    {
        var predicates = Filter.Select(f => f.ToPredicate()).ToList();

        return (obj) => predicates.Any(predicate => predicate(obj));
    }
}


Usage:

// given a List<LocationSelector> coming from the Json
// and a List<MyType> as an input

public List<MyType> FilterByLocation(LocationSelector selector, List<MyType> source)
{
    Func<MyType, bool> locationSelector = selector.ToPredicate();

    return source.Where(obj => locationSelector(obj)).ToList();
}

public Dictionary<string, List<MyType>>(List<LocationSelector> selectors, List<MyType> source)
{
    return selectors.ToDictionary(
        locSelector => locSelector.Name,
        locSelector => FilterByLocation(locSelector, source)
    );
}
```

From this answer you should get:

1. how to treat conditions (`Func<Something, bool>`)
2. how to group conditions with `Any` or `All`

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. I'll try this on monday.